# Laravel inside Wordpress folder, same domain. Is that possible?

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, routes

I have a wordpress blog, and need to configure a laravel application in the same domain.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
www.myWordpressBlog.com
```

and the laravel application should be on

```
www.myWordpressBlog.com/LARAVEL
```

Is it possible? Do i need to change something on laravel routes ?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: It is possible, however if you do control the `myWordpressBlog.com` domain you can just set-up a virtual host like `api.myWordpressBlog.com` or something like that and serve laravel as the root of that. Probably going to be a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately is a requirement to keep this format